# C++ how to use operator overload in another class

Tags: c++

```
class  vec3{
float x;
float y;
float z;

const vec3 & operator= (const vec3 &rvec3)
{
    x = rvec3.x;
    y = rvec3.y;
    z = rvec3.z;
    return *this;
}  };

class vec2{
vec3 vetex;
vec3 normal;

const vec2 & operator = (const vec2 &rvec2)
{
    vetex = rvec2.vetex;
    normal= rvec2.normal;
    return *this;
} };
```

the complier show the error "operator = " is a private member of 'vec3' . How could this happens?

Comment: `class` visibility defaults to `private`.  Add `public:`.

Comment: It seems you want use `struct` for trivial `vec3` and `vec2` instead of `class`.

Comment: Not that it matters much in C++, but then again he'd need the "public:" at the beginning of his classes.

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
class  vec3{
float x;
float y;
float z;

public:
const vec3 & operator= (const vec3 &rvec3)
{
    x = rvec3.x;
    y = rvec3.y;
    z = rvec3.z;
    return *this;
}  };
```

The operator method has become public and it is visible from external code.
Besides the definition of `operator=` in the class `vec2` is unnecessary because it is default behaviour of operator for this class. By the way `operator=` in the `vec3` is unnecessary too.

Maybe you should change  from class to struct.

Answer (score 1):

By default, class members in c++ are private.

To allow external code to see the operator, you need to specify it as public.

```
class  vec3{
float x;
float y;
float z;
public:
const vec3 & operator= (const vec3 &rvec3)
{
    x = rvec3.x;
    y = rvec3.y;
    z = rvec3.z;
    return *this;
}  };
```